# Should we keep symbols/special characters in StringConstants file?

Tags: java, string, memory-management

I have read about it in a several places and also have been guided by my seniors to use String Constants in java. So I usually keep all logging messages and other required string stuff in my `StringConstants` class, which would look something like this:

```
public class StringConstants {

    // Logger Messages
    // Debug
    public static final String DEBUG_ENTERING_METHOD = "Entering Method";
    public static final String DEBUG_LEAVING_METHOD = "Leaving Method";
}
```

Should I also keep special characters/symbols/operators like ':',',' or '=' in this file as final strings?

I ask this because I know that Strings objects are not created again and again if they are in memory. So if I have to do something like

```
logger.error(StringConstants.ERROR_MSG+":"+some_string);
```

Should the colon be in string constants? Will it do me any good?

If something is not clear about my query or doubt, kindly mention it in the comment, I would edit the question.

Comment: For the logger example, I would have the `error` method be used like `logger.error(some_string)`, where `some_string` is the error message. Then, the method would format this message anyway you like (prepending the string `"Error:"`, for example).

Comment: This is an opinion, but to me, the purpose of the StringConstants class is to put all of the application messages in one place.  This makes internationalization a bit easier, as well as correcting any spelling or grammar errors.  The purpose is not to micro-optimize Java.

Comment: Why not extend your StringConstants by one character and include the : within the `StringConstants.ERROR_MSG`?

Comment: as per my understanding logger.error("a"+"b"+"c") will create three string objects? So its not memory effecient! Final String objects will not be created again..

Comment: @SambhavSharma Creating strings becomes a memory problem only on a very large scale and in a short duration of time. You can test it, but maybe thousands of strings in a few seconds will start to show efficiency changes. Don't worry about O(10) strings.

Comment: Also, if you want to chain many strings, use `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer` for concurrency). These are mutable classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use a properties file than either a class or an interface, for holding strings used for messages.  You could even keep the properties file outside of the jar that has your java code.  There are a few advantages.

If you want to change the text of the messages, or have different versions for different languages, you can just put a new properties file in place, and you don't need to rebuild the jar files.

If you use the `PropertyResourceBundle` class properly, the internationalisation happens automatically - you can have different sets of properties co-existing, and the system's locale will be used to select the right one.

The `Logger` class integrates seamlessly with `ResourceBundle`, so you don't have to write any code for looking up the message key.

The `Logger` class lets you use include message parameters (like `{0}, {1}`) and have them expand using parameters that you provide.  There are even some formatting options.  So in the example of your question, you might have a property whose value is `Entering method {0} of class {1}` and just write `logger.log(Level.FINE, "entering", "methodname", "classname");` where "entering" is the key in the properties file.  There is then no need to mess around with `StringBuilder` objects, or `String.format`, or any other message concatenating mechanism.

There are logging frameworks that give you even more goodies than this, but this is too large a topic to go into here.  My point is that using a properties file and a resource bundle will give you a lot, for nothing; and therefore there's no need to even consider having a class or an interface for your constants.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, constants should be defined where they are used.  If they're used in one class, define them in that class.  If they're used in one package, define them in a class in that package.  Define them wherever is most logical, not arbitrarily all in one place.

If you were using a colon as a delimiter, perhaps you'd want a constant for that, since it might make its purpose more clear when you refer to it.  But defining constants just for printing log messages is rather silly, since their exact format shouldn't matter.  And all String literals with the same value refer to the same object, so this

```
final String STRING = "string";
System.out.println(STRING);
System.out.println(STRING);
```

...is essentially the same as

```
System.out.println("string");
System.out.println("string");
```

Both only create one string.

Incidentally, this

```
logger.error("a" + "b" + "c");
```

...could create *five* strings ("a", "b", "c", "ab", and "abc") although I think the compiler might recognize what you're doing and optimize it.  Maybe somebody who knows more about the compiler can shed some light on that.  In any case, don't worry about micro-optimization unless you can show that performance is a problem.  You'll put a lot of effort into it, and the user will never notice that you shaved off a few milliseconds.